# Pandas Not Dropping Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop all duplicates in a dataframe.

I'm using

```
removeDuplicates = data.drop_duplicates()
```

But its just printing the same dataset without dropping the duplicates.

Data Frame Example:

[image]

The first row should be kept, so the second occurence of County 1 aka the duplicate should be dropped. But nothing happens when I run drop duplicates on this

EDIT: Nevermind, it IS printing a different dataframe. I misread the output and confused myself. The second occurrence of County 1 should not be dropped because it is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Show an example of duplicate rows in your dataframe.

Comment: Do you want to drop all rows that have even a single column with the same value of another column? Or just countries?

Comment: A better practice is to use `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`. Don't assign its output `df = ...`, because that return value will be null. Just execute it as a command.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify what column(s) contain(s) duplicates:

```
removeDuplicates = data.drop_duplicates(subset=['COUNTY'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify not to keep any duplicates with the keyword argument `keep`:

```
removeDuplicates = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

From the [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) documentation:

`keep`: Determines which duplicates (if any) to keep.

- `"first"` : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
- `"last"` : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
- `False` : Drop all duplicates.

Note: the above only works on the rows that are completely duplicates of other rows, which in your dataframe, you have no complete duplicates.

If you only want to determine a duplicate by one or more specific columns, you can use the `subset` keyword argument:

```
removeDuplicates = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["COOUNTRY"], keep=False)
```

Also from the above linked documentation:

`subset`: Only consider certain columns for identifying duplicates, by default use all of the columns.

So, you get:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {"COUNTRY": ["Country 1", "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 8"],
      "NAME": ["Kia", "John", "Peter", "Bob"],
      "AGE": [34, 39, 78, 30],
      "YEARS": [18, 6, 5, 2],
      "PREV_STATE": ["FL", "GA", "IN", "NY"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=["COUNTRY"], keep=False))
```

Output:

```
     COUNTRY   NAME  AGE  YEARS PREV_STATE
2  Country 2  Peter   78      5         IN
3  Country 8    Bob   30      2         NY
```

Comment: But `keep='first'` (default) means that all but the first rows are removed, but the OP tells that the dataframe remains the same